# How to Exclude a T4 Template from a NuGet Package

Tags: nuget, t4

I'm creating a NuGet package the provides a client for my WebAPI project by reflecting over the `ApiController`s and creating classes for each one with methods that correspond to the actions defined on the controller. Unfortunately the `.tt` file is being included in the content folder when I run `nuget.exe pack Client.csproj`. I've tried creating a `.nuspec` file with a `<files>` directive, but I can't seem to exclude the file by itself. Does anyone know how to force the package to exclude the T4 template?

The project structure is roughly:

```
Website/
    Controllers/
        UserController.cs
        ...
Client/
    Client.tt
    Client.cs
        namespace Client
            class UserService
            ...
```

And I'd like a NuGet package like:

```
lib/
    net45/
        Client.dll
            namespace Client
                class UserService
```

But I'm getting something like this:

```
content/
    Client.tt
lib/
    net45/
        Client.dll
            namespace Client
                class UserService
                ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the easy solution is to use the `-Exclude` option when creating the package via the command line.

```
NuGet.exe Pack Client.csproj -Exclude *.tt
```

The new package will look exactly as specified in the question.

Comment: A nice gotcha - it doesn't exclude any .tt files in subdirectories, you have to also exclude those in your list.

Comment: To exclude everything, just do -Exclude **/*.tt

Answer (score 8):

```
NuGet.exe Pack Client.csproj -Exclude **/*.tt
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was inside **csproj** file, I had to fix

```
<Content Include="SomeFile.txt" />
```

to

```
<None Include="SomeFile.txt" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on @Baur's answer you can set this:

```
<None Include="SomeFile.tt" />
```

From the IDE, by right clicking the files and going to properties.

Click the BuildAction Property
Set it to None

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure DevOps, I tried for a long time either trying using a custom nuget pack command with the -exclude, which did not work, or tried adding a .nuspec file and excluding the content from there. However, nothing worked.

How I fixed it in our project is clicking on each .tt file and setting the "Build Action" from "Content" to "None". It didn't seem to have an affect on the project in any way.

Maybe someone has a better solution, but I struggled with it for 1-2 days until I decided to screw it and just change the build action.