# NuGet vs Direct Reference of Class w/ EF6 Entities

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a class library with numerous EF6 entities. I generated a NuGet from this library. Whenever I reference the library directly only the DLL is placed in the bin, however when I install the library via NuGet it copies over the entities *Content.tt and *.tt files into a folder in the project.

I have a couple of questions around this difference:

1. Why does the NuGet require these files present when a reference to the project does not?
2. Is there a need for these entity files or am I able to force the NuGet to not clone these files over when installed?

My .nuspec file is standard like follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package >
      <metadata>
        <id>MYID</id>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
        <title>MYTITLE</title>
        <authors>MYNAME</authors>
        <owners></owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description</description>
        <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
        <tags></tags>
      </metadata>
    </package>
```

The commands I am using to generate the package are:

> c:\nuget.exe pack MYID.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop
> Platform=AnyCPU
>
> c:\nuget.exe add MYID.1.0.0.nupkg -Source M:\Dev\NuGetPackages

Comment: Does your Nuget package only contain the DLL (with maybe the PDB and XML documentation files)? What is your nuspec definition?

Comment: Nothing special about my nuspec file. My package contains the full .edmx files for each of my entities. When installing the package in other projects it places only the .Context.tt and .tt files in the solution.

Comment: what is the command you are using to generate the nuget package?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.tt files will not be required unless you are doing runtime code generation. Since you are packaging into a dll, this is a not the case. T4 templates (.tt files) are used by entity framework to generate C# classes from EDMX files, as your objects are changed in the diagram. They will not be required to execute the final code.

Check the answer, [How to Exclude a T4 Template from a NuGet Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657526/how-to-exclude-a-t4-template-from-a-nuget-package), you can exclude .tt files from packaging.

Comment: Oh man! Thank you for this. This is exactly what i needed. I ended up with the following commend to pack the NuGet: c:\nuget.exe pack MYID.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Platform=AnyCPU -Exclude Entities/*/*.tt since all my entities are in the "Entities/DBNAME/" folder. For some reason */*.tt or */*/*.tt or **/*.tt where not doing it for me. Also this little upgrade has saved me hours of time installing this NuGet and wrestling with VSO as it tries to removed folder and add them back into the project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A little research over the web shows that this issue occurred to a lot of users between 3.4.3 version to 3.4.4 version and was addressed at version 3.5.0.

As it seems, it was a Microsoft bug between the packages. I do not know which version you are using, but I recommend to check this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm on EntityFramework 6.1.3. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: With pleasure.  Now, Yes, the nuget package version you are using, not the EF.

Comment: It appears i'm using version 3.4.4.1321 and i says it's up to date, no option for version 3.5.0